# is there a way to perform logic on the following rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
     retailer_id true_channel
28            96      organic
29            96      organic
30            96     retailer
63           174      organic
64           174      organic
65           174     retailer
66           174     retailer
67           174      organic
155          325     retailer
156          325     retailer
```

I want it to look like this

```
     retailer_id true_channel funnel
28            96      organic  organic
29            96      organic  organic
30            96     retailer  then retailer
63           174      organic  organic
64           174      organic  organic
65           174     retailer  then retailer
66           174     retailer  then retailer
67           174      organic  then organic
155          325     retailer  retailer
156          325     retailer  retailer
```

and so on...

I tried creating this code:

```
retailers = visits_orders['retailer_id'].unique()
output = []

for retailer in retailers:
    this_retailer_df = visits_orders.loc[visits_orders['retailer_id']==retailer,'true_channel']
    
    for i,channel in enumerate(this_retailer_df[:-1]):
        
        if i == 0:
                  output.append(channel)
        else:
            
            
            if channel == this_retailer_df.iloc[i + 1]:
                       output.append(channel)
            else:
                       output.append(f"Then {channel}")

visits_orders['funnel_try1'] = output
```

but off course due to poor structure, It produced a lot of NaNs and slow performance.
also, it did not capture the logic that well

Comment: Can you explain the logic?

Comment: I want to create a funnel for each retailer id.
Where if he started with a channel for example a retailer, Moving on the rows, He converted to be organic, The funnel column should capture that change, If he did not change after that, It should keep on repeating "then organic" till it change again, for example to retailer to be 'then retailer', if not it should keep on going that way,

Comment: Got it, see below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with a  [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) to form a [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
# create groups of successive identical true_channel
# per retailer_id and enumerate them
order = (df.groupby('retailer_id', group_keys=False)['true_channel']
           .apply(lambda s: s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum())
        )

# each enumeration that is > 1 is not the first
# let's mask it with the value prepended with "then_"
df['funnel'] = df['true_channel'].mask(order.gt(1), 'then_'+df['true_channel'])
```

Output:

```
     retailer_id true_channel         funnel
28            96      organic        organic
29            96      organic        organic
30            96     retailer  then_retailer
63           174      organic        organic
64           174      organic        organic
65           174     retailer  then_retailer
66           174     retailer  then_retailer
67           174      organic   then_organic
155          325     retailer       retailer
156          325     retailer       retailer
```

Comment: Thank you so much, That did it.
I hope your day is better than you made mine.

Comment: I hope it's not too much to ask you to clarify the logic or show me a source from which I can learn more advanced computations with groupby like this?

Comment: I added comments to the code, I suggest you try to run the individual parts one by one, don"t hesitate to ask if you have specific questions

Comment: Thank you man, I'll try to be better at this, I see a lot of great computations created with groupby similar to the implementation of the filter context in DAX